Autodesk Data Visualization: Heatmap Not Rendering and Sprites Misaligned
I have just cloned the demo project from https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo and run locally

change to my clientid & secret
use rac_basic_sample_project.rvt sample project
rest of the things are same

const SENSORS = {
    'sensor-1': {
        name: 'Living Room',
        description: 'Basic sensor in the middle of the living room.',
        groupName: 'Level 1',
        location: {
            x: 31.92,
            y: 11.49,
            z: -12.97
        },
        objectId: 4124
    },
    'sensor-2': {
        name: 'Dining Table',
        description: 'Basic sensor at the dining table.',
        groupName: 'Level 1',
        location: {
            x: -10,
            y: 41.64,
            z: -12.15
        },
        objectId: 4111
    },
    'sensor-3': {
        name: 'Kitchen',
        description: 'Basic sensor in the kitchen.',
        groupName: 'Level 1',
        location: {
            x: 10,
            y: 41.64,
            z: -12.15
        },
        objectId: 4111
    },
    'sensor-4': {
        name: 'Bedroom',
        description: 'Basic sensor in the bedroom.',
        groupName: 'Level 2',
        location: {
            x: -7.46,
            y: 41.47,
            z: 2.97
        },
        objectId: 4085
    }
};

const CHANNELS = {
    'temp': {
        name: 'Temperature',
        description: 'External temperature in degrees Celsius.',
        type: 'double',
        unit: '°C',
        min: 18.0,
        max: 28.0
    },
    'co2': {
        name: 'CO₂',
        description: 'Level of carbon dioxide.',
        type: 'double',
        unit: 'ppm',
        min: 482.81,
        max: 640.00
    }
};

But this is not working as expected: my sensors are not appearing on right floor, like 3 of them are in floor 1, but 2 are appearing in living room floor and one is appearing in foundation floor:

Neither can I see the heatmap.
Sensor should appear in right floor and right location and the heatmap should be visible.
I'm not getting the room data from the model structure, here is my model loading function.

Expected Result:

The heatmap should render on the model, visually representing data points with color gradients.

Sprites should accurately represent specific data points and be positioned correctly on the model.
Actual Result:

The heatmap does not appear at all, even though data points are available.

Sprites are rendered but are not positioned correctly on the model (misaligned), it is not even placed in same level.







getting this in console   error in console

export function loadModel(viewer: any, urn: string) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc: any) {
      const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry(true);
      resolve(viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable));
    }
    function onDocumentLoadFailure(code: any, message: any, errors: any) {
      reject({ code, message, errors });
    }
    window.Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  });
}



Also whenever I tanslate file to SVF by sending the following JSON to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job getting Extractor error code -777 while loading model
{
input: {
urn: urn,
},
output: {
formats: [
{
type: 'svf2',
views: ['2d', '3d'],
advanced: {
generateMasterViews: true,
},
},
],
},
};

Based on the description of the issue it looks like you might be missing the room information in the Revit design that you're loading into the viewer. Please try and get the APS extension for Visual Studio Code (disclaimer: I'm the author), configure it with your client ID/secret, check your Revit model through there, and see if it includes the room data. If not, you can also use the VSCode extension to translate the design again, with generateMasterViews enabled.
